# choosing $3$ numbers from a set of $n$ numbers so no consecutive numbers are selected

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A  = \{1,2,3, \ldots , n\}$
and the question is: in how many ways can you pick $3$ numbers from $A$, so there won't be any consecutive numbers.

I was thinking of a recursive solution:

$A_k =$ number of ways of picking $k$ numbers without consecutive numbers.

$a_3 =$ if $1$ is chosen then any legal pick of size $a_{k-2}$ is ok.

$a_3 =$ if $n$ is chosen, same case.

$a_3 =$ if $2$ till $n-2$ is chosen then any legal pick of size $a_{k-3}$ is ok

---

However, I am not sure if I could actually come up with an actual solution while dealing with two variables.

Could someone please suggest a good approach to this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For a recursive solution, try splitting your choices into two kinds: those where you pick $n$, and those where you don't.  However, this recursive approach requires you to know the solution when you are picking $2$ numbers instead of $3$; this is easier to do directly, or you can similarly (first) solve it recursively as well.  A couple of direct, non-recursive solutions are given below though.

Comment: While doing so, I ended up with the polynom : x^3 - 2x -n+2 = 0 and I can't seem to generalize a close forumla since n can be any number greater than 4.

Comment: The recursion will be of the form $a_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$, where the first term comes from not picking $n$, and the second term comes from picking $n$, and hence picking the remaining two numbers from $[n-2]$.  Note that this is not a constant-coefficient recurrence relation for the sequence $(a_n)$, since the term $b_n$ depends on $n$, so the ordinary exponential formula doesn't work.  However, if you have a guess for the answer (by inspection of the first few terms, say), then you can use this recurrence relation (together with a closed form for $b_n$) to prove your guess is correct.

Comment: Or you can apply the recurrence repeatedly to obtain $a_n = \sum_{k = 3}^{n-2} b_k$, and then evaluate that sum to get a closed form for $a_n$.  This approach is taken in one of the answers below.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Note that if a recursive solution is found in $2$ variables it is not necessary to get the closed formula; see this [answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3526775/432081) $\quad$ For fun I ran the Python recursion for $n = 100$ and $r = 3$. $\quad$ Output; $g(100,3)  = 152096$. $\quad$ For larger $n$ I started getting *RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison* error. So the program needs to be recast (until you 'discover' the closed formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the set of $n$ integers.

Either you take $1$ or you do not. If you take $1$, then you can't take $2$, so you have to pick $2$ numbers out of $n-2$ numbers which are not consecutive.

If you don't pick $1$, then you get the same situation for $n-1$ numbers.

Hence, $a_n = a_{n-1} + m_{n-2}$, where $m_{n-2}$ is the number of ways of picking two non-consecutive numbers from a list of $n-2$ numbers. Let's study $m$.

Consider $n-2$ numbers. If you pick $1$, you can pick all except $2$, so that gives $(n-4)$ ways. Similarly,  if you pick $2$, you can pick all except $1$ and $3$. Thus, every number except $1$ and $n-2$ admits $n-5$ valid choices, while $1$ and $(n-2)$ themselves admit $(n-4)$ valid choices. Hence $m_{n-2} = 2(n-4) + (n-4)(n-5) = (n-4)(n-3)$. However, every choice comes twice, because it's possible that we first choose $1$ then $3$, while the next time we choose $3$ and $1$, which amount to the same choice but are counted differently here. So we have to divide by $2$.

That gives $a_n = a_{n-1}+ \frac{1}{2}(n-4)(n-3)$. Now, we can perform the addition: $a_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_4^n n^2-7n+12 = \dfrac{n^3-9n^2+26n-24}{6}  = \dfrac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{6}$

As an example, let us consider $5$:
$$
a_5=\frac{3*2*1}{6} = 1
$$

Similarly,
$$
a_6=\frac{4*3*2}{6} = 4
$$
which is true, because $1,3,5$, $1,3,6$, $1,4,6$ and $2,4,6$ are the only satisfactory triples.

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand why this is true: "If you don't pick 1, then you get the same situation for n−1 numbers." , If you pick n, instead of 1, you come across the same exact situation has the first one.

Comment: It doesn't makea difference whether you pick $n$ or $1$. In the end, the problem is picking $3$ non-consecutive numbers out of a set of $n-1$ consecutive numbers, which comes about either by deleting $1$ or $n$ (one of the end points) from the set of consecutive numbers. It does not matter which one I delete, the answer will be the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that yields an explicit formula:

Place $n - 3$ blue balls in a row, leaving spaces between them and at the ends of the row.  There are $n - 2$ such spaces, $n - 4$ spaces between successive blue balls and two at the ends of the row.  Choose three of these $n - 2$ spaces in which to place the three green balls.  Now, number the balls from $1$ to $n$ from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of three numbers of set $A$ in which no two elements of the subset are consecutive.  The number of ways of choosing the subset is equal to the number of ways of placing the three green balls in the $n - 2$ spaces, which is $$\binom{n - 2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Make this question in some parts:

> 1.We first choose $1$:Then we cannot choose either $2$then it's answer will be $f_{n-2}$
>
> 2.For any other numbers that we choose first except $n$ you can't either take other two that are next to it that this kinds will give us the answer $n-2(f_{n-3})$
>
> 3.And for $n$ the answer will be $f_{n-2}$

Then the totall answer will be:

$f_n=2f_{n-2}+(n-2)f_{n-3}$

**Hint for solving upper equation**:Because $n=0$ and $n=1$ is impossible you should try $n=5$ and $n=6$.

Comment: looks great, thanks. however, the suitable polynom would come up with an extra variable to deal with, :

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the three numbers chosen, in order, are $a$, $b$ and $c$.  We then have $1 \le a < b < c \le n$.  However, since we know the numbers are not consecutive, we in fact have some stronger inequalities: $a + 2 \le b$, and $b + 2 \le c$.

However, having the $+2$ makes things a little inconvenient.  One way to get rid of them is to change variables slightly: make the larger ones a bit smaller.

Full solution:

> Let $b' = b-1$ and $c' = c-2$.  Then we have $b' = b - 1 \ge (a+2) - 1 = a+1$, or simply $b' > a$.  Similarly, $c' = c - 2 \ge (b + 2) - 2 = b = b' + 1$, or $c' > b'$.  We also have $c' = c - 2 \le n - 2$.  Hence with the new variables, the conditions can be simplified to $1 \le a < b' < c' \le n - 2$.  That is, $\{a, b', c'\}$ is a set of three distinct integers between $1$ and $n-2$.  By definition of the binomial coefficient, there are $\binom{n-2}{3}$ ways of choosing $\{a, b', c'\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, let $n\geq 0$ and $k\geq 0$ be integers.  Then, the number of ways to choose $k$ non-consecutive elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is $\dbinom{n-k+1}{k}$.  If the $k$ chosen numbers must differ by at least $d$ for some fixed integer $d\geq 0$, then the answer is $\dbinom{n-(d-1)(k-1)}{k}$.