# In how many ways can we pick $t$ different numbers out of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that no consecutive numbers are picked

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can we pick $t$ different numbers out of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that no consecutive numbers are picked

---

I am aware that there is a solution [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490405/choosing-numbers-without-consecutive-numbers)
but the final answer is not really important , I am trying to understand this.

I asked my professor for a hint and she said try to think of a binary sequence.

so what I tried was suppose that every number pick will be given the number $"1"$ and not picked will be $"0"$ so now the problem is to make a binary sequence such that that are no two $1$ after the other

suppose there are $t$ ones then we have $n-t$ zeros

I tried to think of a simpler case say $n=7$ and $t=3$ so the set is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ but my problem was now picking the edges ($1,7$) there are options there, the sequence can begin with a zero but also end with one and same thing for the end how to handle these cases?

this is where I got stuck , I know the final answer should be $\binom{(n-2r+1)+(r+1)-1}{(r+1)-1}=\binom{n-r+1}r$

but I am not able to get there myself ..
how can I continue from where I got stuck?

Thanks for any tips and help !

Comment: You have all the ingredients needed to solve the problem.  Consider a sequence 'valid' if it's $0$s represent skipped numbers and $1$s represent picked numbers. You have figured out that the 'valid' sequence of $0$s and $1$s can start with $0$ and end with a $1$. However, every $1$ apart from the last is followed by a $0$. So, a 'valid' sequence can look like this $\_10\_10\_10\_\dots \_1\_$ where the underscores are filled with the remaining $0$s.

Comment: @UmeshShankar This is my question , how many zeros are there left? is it $n-t-(t-1)$ because of how it can end with a $1$? and what if it begin with 1 and end with 1 then would it be $n-t-(t-2)$?

Comment: If it begins with one, the next one should be a zero. The only one that needn’t be followed by zero is the last one. The no. of zeroes left are $n-2t+1$.